# Avoid argument duplication in rambda

Tags: javascript, rambda.js

```
import { pipe } from 'rambda';
function readFile(filePath) { // reading the file return fileContents }
function editFile(fileContents) { // edit the file return newFileContents }
function writeFile(fileContents, filePath) { // write content  }

function manipulateFile(filePath) {
  return writeFile(pipe(readFile, editFile)(filePath))(filePath);
}
```

is there any way to avoid `filePath` argument duplication in `manipulateFile`?

Ideally I would like to pipe it like this. But `filePath` will be not provided to `writeFile`

```
function manipulateFile(filePath) {
  return pipe(
    readFile,
    editFile,
    writeFile
  )(filePath)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chain` combinator to pass the same argument to multiple nested function calls.

Here is an excerpt from [common combinators in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45):

> ```
> const S_ = f => g => x => f (g (x)) (x)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> | Name | # | Haskell | Ramda | Sanctuary | Signature |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | chain | S_ | `(=<<)` | `chain` | `chain` | `(a → b → c) → (b → a) → b → c` |

To make it more obvious how it is relevant here, consider this - your `manipulateFile` can be re-written as:

```
function manipulateFile(filePath) {
  const f = writeFile;
  const g = pipe(readFile, editFile);
  const x = filePath;

  return f (g (x)) (x);
}
```

Which matches exactly with the `S_` body and can thus be represented as `S_(f)(g)(x)`.

Using the [Rambda `chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) you can use:

```
import { pipe, chain } from 'ramda';
function readFile(filePath) { // reading the file return fileContents }
function editFile(fileContents) { // edit the file return newFileContents }
function writeFile(fileContents, filePath) { // write content  }

function manipulateFile(filePath) {
  return chain(writeFile, pipe(readFile, editFile))(filePath);
}
```

or reduce it to point-free:

```
const manipulateFile = chain(writeFile, pipe(readFile, editFile));
```

It seems that [the Rambda `chain`](https://github.com/selfrefactor/rambda#chain) does not work the same way as Ramda does.

Comment: Got `TypeError: list.map is not a function`

Comment: Oh, I see. Appears that `chain` is in ram(b)da is not fully equal to the chain combinator. Give me a bit to do some more research.

Comment: Never mind, just installed ramda. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad it works. Perhaps Rambda is wrong or slightly outdated in this case.